# 'after' with subordinating clauses

Tags: tense, usage, clauses

Are these grammatically and sequentially correct tenses? Sequence of tenses with subordinating conjunction "**after**"?

- He comes after I come.
- He comes after I came.

Which is correct one?

Comment: You should write better examples. Yours don't have enough information to understand what is happening (the context).  For example, "He comes to the door after I *come/came* home."

Answer (score 1):

- **He comes after I come.** - *Is a general thing he generally does. Whenever I come, he comes after me.*
- **He comes after I came.** - *Is grammatically wrong since you can't use a completed past action with a present habit. The right structure in this case will be, "**He came after I came.**" We place the whole action into the past making it a bygone event.*

Comment: Are these have same meaning ?? Can we use these interchangeably?? 1)He comes after I come==He comes after me and 2) He comes before I come==He comes before me.

Comment: @nandy Yes, **He comes after I come**=**He comes after me** and **He comes before I come**=**He comes before me**

Comment: I remember there was "he comes after I have come" on which you did leave a comment.  Maybe I'm mistaken, but if I'm not, was that a valid construction?

Comment: @Rompey I asked whether somebody can give reference to whether it is grammatically correct. I never met it before I saw it here just yesterday.

Comment: He knows that I came. Is this sentence correct with past simple subordinate clause?

Answer (score 0):

While the first sentence is *grammatically* correct, it wouldn't be common to use this with *come*, and especially not using the present tense.   You might use a different verb when talking about instructions or plans of some kind:

> A: During the ceremony, when does John **enter** the room?
>   B: He **enters** after I **enter**.
>   A: And when do you **come in**?
>   B: I **come in** after Beth **comes in**.

It would not be logical to use the past tense, as in your second example, but you can use the past perfect:

> B: He will enter after I **have entered**.

However, you would not ordinarily repeat the verb.  Instead simply use "have":

> B: He will enter after I **have**.

or omit the second verb altogether:

> B: He will enter after **me**.

---

Point of interest:  The verb "to come" is a synonym for "to have an orgasm".  In this context, *He comes after I come,* could make perfect sense -- although probably not what you meant when you wrote it.